# How to make Xcode find .h file in signdoc framework

Tags: ios7

I have signdociosfoundations.framework, I tried to import a header inside it: `SDSignatureHandler.h`. But it said: "`signdociosfoundations/SDSignatureHandler.h` not found". I tried to remove it from my project and add it again in Link Binaries to Library not it does not work to me. Moreover, I pressed Command + click to Jump to definition, it also take me to this file. Anybody help me please! Thank in advance.
[image]

Comment: Did you include the framework via Target Settings > Build Phases > Link Binaries With Libraries ?

Comment: Did you read my post carefully? I told that I remove and framework to Link Binaries to Library.

Comment: @PhongNguyen, is there any official document for signdoc because I also facing some problem with framework?